# How to use a distribution-specific package file

Tags: apt, dependencies, compiling, repository

I want to compile KiCad ver 6.0 on my Ubuntu 22.0 WSL2 instance. The [build guide states](https://dev-docs.kicad.org/en/build/linux/) that there is a distribution-specific packages that has to be installed in order for a succesful build. [The file is hosted here](https://gitlab.com/kicad/packaging/kicad-ubuntu-builder/kicad-daily-package/-/blob/dailybuild/debian/control), but I have no idea how can I use this file? My guess is the file should be called with a command that pulls and installs all the packages named in the file.

Can you please tell me how to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Why do you want to *compile* it, specifically? [kicad 6.0.2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kicad) appears to be available from the universe repository

Comment: @steeldriver well I want to do some changes in the source code :D

Comment: OK well since you are trying to build the same major version that's already in the repo, installing *that* version's `build-deps` is likely equivalent

Comment: ... otherwise, the only way I'm aware of to use the control file information in that way is via a low-level devscript - see for example [How to install build dependencies directly from the debian/control file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19432425/4440445)

Comment: Check what release you're actually using; 0 is an invalid month.  Ubuntu's main products are *year.month* in format, with 22.04 representing the 2022-April release (2000 being added to the *year*), with specialist *snap* only products using the *year* format, so 22 for the *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS that is *snap* package only.  Your 22.0 makes no sense; you'll find there is another number making it 10 (October) or 04 (April) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written in the build guide, you need to install packages mentioned in Depends and Build-Depends fields.

The packages are installed by `sudo apt install`.

For example:

```
sudo apt install doxygen
```

As @steeldriver mentioned this software can be found in Ubuntu repos. So running

```
sudo apt build-deps kicad
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks, I know the apt install X, I was thinking that I can feed this file into a command and it installs the packages automatically?

Comment: Actually you can use a few packages delimited by space. Also you need only Build-Depends. After you build a package "Depends" will really be installed automatically by apt.